# When did Apple start manufacturing the Mac outside the USA?

Tags: mac

I thought I'd be able to find the answer to this on wikipedia.  No luck.  The best I can find so far is a pic of the original 128k mac:

[image]

Comment: good candidate for community wiki...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer your question, but check out [Coconut Identity Card](http://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutidentitycard/index.html).

Comment: i was about to vote you down, but it is at least mac-related... :)

Comment: "coconutIdentityCard is a small app that reads out *where* and when your Mac and your iPod were built by Apple."  I'd say it's more closely related than you give me credit for. :)

Comment: Not really since it's not compatible with OS 9, which is still after they moved out of the USA.

Answer (score 1):

1980: Ireland

http://ecommerce.hostip.info/pages/51/Apple-Computer-Inc-EARLY-HISTORY.html

Don't miss the link to the next page at the bottom for more history.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good [history of the company](http://www.answers.com/topic/apple-computer-inc) on Answers.com, but I don't think it deals with where they are made.

Another place to look at (it's an interesting read) would be [Apple-History.com](http://www.apple-history.com/).